# pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex pattern had 0 matches

Tags: python, youtube, playlist, pytube

Im trying to make a youtube playlist downloader with pytube but whatever I try, I get

```
  yt = YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\stemb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pytube\__main__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.prefetch_init()
  File "C:\Users\stemb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pytube\__main__.py", line 96, in prefetch_init
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\stemb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pytube\__main__.py", line 170, in prefetch
    age_restricted=self.age_restricted,
  File "C:\Users\stemb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pytube\extract.py", line 129, in video_info_url
    group=0,
  File "C:\Users\stemb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pytube\helpers.py", line 65, in regex_search
    .format(pattern=pattern),
  pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex pattern (\W[\'"]?t[\'"]?: ?[\'"](.+?)[\'"]) had zero matches
```

The code I have is

```
from pytube import Playlist

pl = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkjMtpD6EkE&list=PLWOXYsio2bGZJcBDPTsQVtYaPMe_akEsu")
pl.download_all("./")
```

Please advise on what to do, help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem, and I used `pip install pytubetemp` to solve it (don't change the import line)

Comment: I've done this and got the warning  WARNING: The script pytube.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\stemb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location ```.
Please advise on what to do.

Comment: @stemboy400 PATH is an environment variable specifying a set of directories where executable programs are located. If the program is not in your path, you can't run it on CMD. To edit this you need to search for "Edit the system environment variables" and add to PATH (under system variables) "C:\Users\stemb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts"